# Text match SQL query that finds similar matches based on a subject, but restricts the exact match

Tags: sql, laravel, postgresql, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I'm creating a bug tracking tool and attempting to add the ability to find similar bugs, excluding the bug that you are searching based on. I'm using Laravel 5.7/eloquent and postgreSQL. The current raw query looks like:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM bugs 
WHERE 
    subject::text like 'Delectus iusto est architecto magni expedita eum rerum consequatur.' 
OR 
    description::text like 'Delectus iusto est architecto magni expedita eum rerum consequatur.'
AND 
    id <> 'e0433097-d2b0-49ac-8aea-fcdbefa378b5'
```

The eloquent version is extracted into a BugSearch class, but essentially does this:

```
$builder = DB::table('bugs');
$builder->where('subject', 'like', $bug->subject)
        ->orWhere('description', 'like', $bug->description);
```

And returns the builder, at which point I try to add on the where clause:

```
$matches = $builder->where('id', '!=', $bug->id)->get();
return response()->json($matches);
```

This is clearly not working as a raw query or with eloquent's query builder, as both return exact matches, which need to be filtered out by the where clause.

Answer (score 1):

You did not say explicitly what is "not working" in your query...

However based on your post, you might just be running into an *operator prescedence* issue. `and` has highest prescedence than `or`, hence you probably want to enclose your `or`s into parens.

Also, if you are looking to use the `LIKE` operator, you need to surround the search string with the percent sign (`%`).

```
select * from bugs 
where 
( 
    subject::text like '%Delectus iusto est architecto magni expedita eum rerum consequatur.%' 
    or description::text like '%Delectus iusto est architecto magni expedita eum rerum consequatur.%' 
)
and id <> 'e0433097-d2b0-49ac-8aea-fcdbefa378b5'
```

Without parens, the query is actually equivalent to :

```
select * from bugs 
where 
subject::text like 'Delectus iusto est architecto magni expedita eum rerum consequatur.' 
or 
( 
    or description::text like 'Delectus iusto est architecto magni expedita eum rerum consequatur.' 
    and id <> 'e0433097-d2b0-49ac-8aea-fcdbefa378b5' 
)
order by created_at desc
```

Comment: Ah yes. Do you know how to replicate that with Laravel's query builder?

Comment: OK, so updated my answer accordingly. I am not very familiar with Lavarel however, so cannot give you the exact syntax (would need to look at the docs)

Comment: Welcome @MattLarson !

Answer (score 1):

I actually solved this by passing the `->where('id', '!=', $bug->id);` in the BugSearch class' constructor.